# Rust: simple simultaneous iteration of two hashmaps without zipping

Tags: rust

I'm trying to simulataneously loop over two maps with a key, without calling zip().
I can't seem to get the following code to work. What am I doing wrong?

`main.rs`

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

mod iteratemaps;

fn main() {
    let mut m1 = HashMap::new();
    m1.insert(0, 10);
    m1.insert(1, 11);
    m1.insert(2, 12);

    let mut m2 = HashMap::new();
    m2.insert(0, 20);
    m2.insert(1, 21);
    m2.insert(2, 22);

    iteratemaps::iterate_maps(&m1, &m2);
}
```

`iteratemaps.rs`

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

pub fn iterate_maps(
    m1: &HashMap<u32, i32>,
    m2: &HashMap<u32, i32>,
) {
    // doesn't work
    for i in 0..m1.len() {
        println!("{:?}, {:?}", m1.get(&i), m2.get(&i));
    }

    // works
    // for (k, e1) in m1.iter() {
    //     let mut e2 = m2.get(k);
    //     println!("{:?}, {:?}", e1, e2)
    // }
}
```

The error I'm getting is:

```sh
9 |         println!("{:?}, {:?}", m1.get(&i), m2.get(&i));
  |                                       ^^ expected `u32`, found `usize
```

Comment: Well, `m1.len()` returns a `usize`, while your keys are `u32`. One needs to be converted to the other explicitly. That said, if your keys are always sequential like that, wouldn't a Vec theoretically be better than a HashMap?

Comment: yes, I understand I need to cast to u32, I don't seem to get the syntax right. How would that be?
Yes, a Vec would make sense, but this is a minimal example. I need a HashMap here.

Comment: `i as u32` should work. Do note that such primitive cast will silently overflow in case `i` is larger than a `u32` can hold.

Comment: What is the reason you can't use `zip`?

Comment: because I want to traverse the two maps in sequence with the same key.
I would like to do a result[i] = m1[i] * m2[i]. Perhaps I'm doing something wrong, but could not fetch the same indexes from the m1 and m2 maps using zip.

Comment: It occurred to me that another option is to use [`BTreeMap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.BTreeMap.html) instead of a `HashMap`. Since a `BTreeMap` has ordered keys, `zip()` will just work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can cast `i` to `u32` as mentioned in the comments, but a more robust solution is to just iterate over the *keys* of one of the hash maps. This has the advantage of not only automatically providing the correct type (it will even be a reference, which is what you need to pass to `HashMap::get`), but it will work even if you move away from contiguous integer keys. For example:

```
pub fn iterate_maps(m1: &HashMap<u32, i32>, m2: &HashMap<u32, i32>) {
    for k in m1.keys() {
        println!("{:?}, {:?}", m1.get(k), m2.get(k));
    }
}
```

You can avoid an unnecessary hash table lookup by iterating over both keys and values of the first hashmap, and only looking up the keys in the second one:

```
pub fn iterate_maps(m1: &HashMap<u32, i32>, m2: &HashMap<u32, i32>) {
    for (k, v1) in m1 {
        let v2 = m2.get(k);
        println!("{:?}, {:?}", v1, v2);
    }
}
```

While working on this code, an additional improvement comes to mind: it could return an *iterator* over keys and values in both hashmaps, so that the caller gets to decide how to use the values. (You can think of the iterator as a variant of the `zip` that actually works for your use case.) While at it, we can make the function generic over the key and value types, so that it works for any kind of hashmap. The result looks like this:

```
pub fn iterate_maps<'a: 'b, 'b, K: Eq + Hash, V>(
    m1: &'a HashMap<K, V>,
    m2: &'b HashMap<K, V>,
) -> impl Iterator<Item = (&'a K, &'a V, &'b V)> {
    m1.iter().map(move |(k, v1)| (k, v1, m2.get(k).unwrap()))
}

// later, in main:
for (_k, v1, v2) in iteratemaps::iterate_maps(&m1, &m2) {
    println!("{:?}, {:?}", v1, v2);
}
```

Finally, an unrelated note: in Rust you can specify a module inline using the `mod modname { ... block ...}` syntax. This would allow you to provide the whole code in one snippet in the question, as shown [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e6fa4d254730cec87a0bd629d09c161d).